# Firebase Authentication Rules Using the Data Inside

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How can I authenticate that only users with the data contents can write/remove the node? My data structure looks like this:

```
project-xxxxxxxx
   Messages
      Chat-Record-001
         User1: "B3xUEsPRZ1XhIAhDQo1DEyLZlSX2"
         User2: "PR70j0ou4JdDWf8S5X9h9BUevpo1"
         Message: "This is a test message!"
      Chat-Record-002
         User1: "RiGLv20W7UTFZSCAATOHsk9gDfg1"
         User2: "GG50j0ou4JdDWf8S5X9h9BUevpo1"
         Message: "This is a test message!"
      Chat-Record-003
         User1: "gBTtYUAKCIVZkYGY7gTUNidSIfv1"
         User2: "gmIOwzJwvSOOQc1ADMrHI6phGIv2"
         Message: "This is a test message!"
      Chat-Record-004
         User1: "B3xUEsPRZ1XhIAhDQo1DEyLZlSX2"
         User2: "gmIOwzJwvSOOQc1ADMrHI6phGIv2"
         Message: "This is a test message!"
```

How should I write the rules so that the user
**B3xUEsPRZ1XhIAhDQo1DEyLZlSX2** can only write to **Chat-Record-001** and **Chat-Record-004** while **gmIOwzJwvSOOQc1ADMrHI6phGIv2** can only write to **Chat-Record-003** and **Chat-Record-004**. The User1 and User2 strings are from createUserWithEmailAndPassword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Messages": {
      "$chatid": {
        ".write": "data.child('User1').val == auth.uid || data.child('User2').val == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this only allows them to update existing messages. If you also want the user to be able to write new messages, as long as their UID is in `User1` or `User2` it'd be:

```
".write": "newData.child('User1').val == auth.uid || newData.child('User2').val == auth.uid"
```

Comment: Yes, I think this will do the trick. I really don't care if there will be millions of messages as long as they can only edit/write on message threads that they're in.